# Other ways of getting in/out of Wakanda?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, black-panther

Passing into Wakanda has been shown twice: in *Black Panther* and in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

Each time a person/group is shown entering Wakanda, they do so by flying a plane and plunging into a [seemingly] illusory forest at a very specific coordinate, which then grants them passage.

*But, what about if you're on foot, just walking?* Would it still possible to get into/out of Wakanda then?

### Ultimately, does entry into Wakanda *have* to be by plane, and at that exact coordinate always? Or, are there other ways?

Comment: Considering the huge spaceships from Infinity War could not have come through the same forest co-ordinates, there has got to be another way...

Comment: One does not simply walk into Wakanda. ...I'm sorry, but it had to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ultimately, does entry into Wakanda have to be by plane...

## No...

You can enter Wakanda in any way you want but the entry methods are protected.

Firstly, of course, you have to know that the super-secret Wakanda exists but let's assume that you do.

Then it's *really* hard to get to in the second place.

> The Black Panther film further established that...it is a landlocked country in the central mountains far from the coasts. **Impassable mountains and jungles around its borders** have helped Wakanda isolate itself from outsiders.
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakanda_(comics))</sup>

If you DO know, *and* manage to pentrate to the interior then you have to cross the border itself...but the borders are patrolled and protected by [The Border Tribe](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Border_Tribe)

> The Border Tribe is a Wakandan tribe tasked with protecting the nation from foreign threats.

---

> At that exact coordinate always?

### Probably not

Killmonger would not know the coordinates (unless his father told him and there is no indication of that) but still manages to fly into Wakanda.

It's apparently also worth noting that the *majority* of Wakanda is undeveloped and it appears that the major/capital city is the primary developed / advanced area. We see extensive jungle / farmscapes but very few *apparent* advancements in the outskirts of the country.

Answer (score 0):

### No.

**Wakanda can also be reached by water.** In *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever*, K'uk'ulkan / Namor and the Talokanil were able to enter Wakanda undetected by swimming or riding aquatic creatures through its waterways.

Relevant dialogue:

> **River Tribe Elder** (*referring to how Namor got to Wakanda*)**:** So, he swam underwater for 100 kilometers.

> **Shuri** (*giving orders to defend Wakanda against the Talokanil*)**:** Fortify the sonic barriers for all waterways.